# implicit conversions with user defined types?

Tags: type-conversion, julia

With the following code:

```
import Base.convert

abstract type MySequential end

struct MyFiniteSequence{T} <: MySequential
       vec::NTuple{N,T} where N
end

Base.convert(MyFiniteSequence, r) = MyFiniteSequence{typeof(r)}((r,))
```

Now try:

```
julia> convert(MyFiniteSequence, 1)
MyFiniteSequence{Int64}((1,))
```

So far so good. Now try to do an implict conversion:

```
julia> MyFiniteSequence(1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching MyFiniteSequence(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  MyFiniteSequence(::Tuple{Vararg{T,N}} where N) where T at REPL[2]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1
```

I think there is a problem because of the {T, N} annotations, but am unsure how the syntax of convert needs to be changed. Is there a way to define convert to get the implicit conversion from Int to struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe implicit constructor calls to `convert` were removed in the transition from julia `0.7` to `1.0`. But you can just define a constructor that calls `convert` if that's what you want:

```
julia> MyFiniteSequence(x) = Base.convert(MyFiniteSequence, x)
MyFiniteSequence

julia> MyFiniteSequence(1)
MyFiniteSequence{Int64}((1,))
```

Comment: Remembering what changed in 1.0 can be a problem when starting with older Julia 0.6 code. Thanks!

Comment: If you're starting from 0.6, I highly recommend taking the intermediate step of using 0.7, as it provides deprecation warnings for the vast majority of the things that changed. Good luck!